# SQL - Presto: Create a new table that counts values without duplicates having issues (AWS Athena)

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I have a response_data_v0 that contains several duplicates of the UUID values that I want to ignore, keeping just the value that contains the oldest date (In other words, I only want the row with the first appearance of that specific UUID)

I built a temporary table using "with" and I filter it by getting "min(uuid)" as a column just to get unique values, then I created a second one that counts those values.

Given that the values of the UUID must be unique (following my logic), I created a validation column "excess_data" to test my hypotheses. All the values of "excess_data" should be `= 0` if I am not getting duplicates in the first table given that

```
count(uuid) = count(distinct uuid)
```

In this specific case.

BUT, that is not happening, `"excess_data" > 0` in all my results.

What am I doing wrong??

```
with unique_values as (SELECT 
    min(uuid) as uuid,
    url,
    day,
    month,
    year
    --response_data
FROM "data_lake"."response_data_v0" 
group by url, day, month, year
--order by uuid
)

SELECT 
    count(uuid) as count_uuids, 
    count(distinct uuid) as count_unique_uuids, 
    count(uuid) - count(distinct uuid) as excess_data,
    month,
    year
FROM unique_values
group by year, month
order by year, month
```

Comment: uuids should be for every row unique as the name suggests, while MIN(uuid) will bring a uuid, but if it is the right one , must you decide, but the count will be always equal

Comment: Yes, the uuids should be unique, but they are matching the urls, and if the urls repeat, the uuids will too. What I am trying to do is creating a temporary table that does not inherit that issue

Comment: So if they repeat why are you wondering about different counts?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the problem here is the different group clauses used to filter out duplicates and to verify that filtering. Unless business logic of the app creating the data prevents the same `uuid` from appearing on different days the observed behavior pretty much is bound to happen - `unique_values` grouping clause includes `day`, while the final select - does not. Either add `day` to the result query group by clause or remove it from `unique_values`'s.

Answer (score 0):

PrestoDB/Trino have a [`min_by`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#min_by) aggregate function that returns the value of a column associated with the minimum value of another column (of the group). `min_by(uuid, my_date)` would return the value of the `uuid` column of the row with the minimum value of `my_date` in the group. Just assemble a string from your year, month, day columns and use that in place of `my_date`.